# Is there a pytorch function to compute fourier integrals

Tags: pytorch, fft, autograd

I have this monstrous function

$f(x,p,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sech^{2}(x + y/2)sech^{2}(x - y/2) × [2 sinh(x + y/2) sinh(x − y/2) + \sqrt(2) sinh(x − y/2)exp(i3t/2) +\sqrt(2) sinh(x + y/2)exp(-i3t/2) + 1]exp(−ipy)dy$

This is essentially a Fourier transform but there is a shift involved. In any case, I know scipy_integrate can handle this integral. But my goal is to plug in tensors in this function W so that I can use the autograd module to compute partial derivatives. Is there some way in pytorch I can approximate this integral. I can write out a Simpson’s rule formula but wondering if there is a better approximation out there in pytorch before I write my substandard approximations.

Thank you very much for your help.